# What is the best library for HTTP/1.1 persistent("Connection: Close") connections in Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-1.1

I must choose a library for connecting to http endpoint. Http connection version is **"1.1"**. Server sends data to client continuously after opening the connection. So, connection is persistent; **"Connection: Close"**.

For this purpose, Which library is better? Is there any benchmark of these libraries such as performance, reliability etc.?

**1. Apache Http Client?**

**2.  HttpURLConnection(Standart Java Http Library)?**

Answer (score 1):

there is this legacy [HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class in JDK, and there's a new API in JDK 11, that supports both HTTP/1.1 and 2.
It contains a new module called java.net.http which exports a package of the same name and is defined in JDK11

```
module java.net.http {

  exports java.net.http;
}
```

[here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-11-standardized-http-client-api) is a very good article on the new JDK11 API